I want to configure my django admin as subdomain on nginx
I've configured Nginx to proxy requests for admin.myproject.com to my Django application running on port 8000. However, when accessing admin.myproject.com, it redirects to admin.myproject.com/admin and displays a "502 Bad Gateway" error.
Here's my Nginx configuration for admin.myproject.com:
`server {
listen 80;
server_name admin.myproject.com;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

}`
I expect requests to admin.myproject.com to be proxied to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin without displaying /admin in the browser. However, it currently adds /admin to the URL and results in a "502 Bad Gateway" error. The Django application is correctly configured to handle requests to /admin.
